# Div inside a td is not stretching to fit on zoom in and zoom out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and I am using a leaflet map in one of td of that table. 
Now when I zoom in or zoom out the website in browser the div inside td (leaflet map section) is not getting fit or autoadjusted in the td itself. It goes out of the td height and width. Any suggestion how i can resolve this?

I have created a similar sort of fiddle :- 
http://jsfiddle.net/7a85hagm/

```
<table style="width: 80%; height: 200px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;" border="1" id='mapContent'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map" style="width: 78%;height: 50%;position: absolute;border:1px solid red;">
        abc
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `position: relative` on the `<td>` and set the `width` of the `<div>` to `100%`;

The way you do it is extremely fragile. Please also note that 1% width does not correspond to 1px border. I also recommend `box-sizing: border-box;` for the `<div>` so its border does not overlap with the `<td>`'s border.

You should also remove the padding from the `<td>` via `padding: 0px;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you should get rid of the position absolute in the div:

```css
#mapContent{
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  border-spacing: 0; 
}

#map{
  width: 78%;
  height: 50%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id='mapContent'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map">abc</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```